# What happens in `pandas.DataFrame.hist`?

Tags: pandas, histogram

What happens under the hood when we run `pandas.DataFrame.hist` on a `DataFrame`?

Can we get the data out as a `DataFrame` instead of plotting a graph?

Comment: what happen i think pandas call `matplotlib.pyplot.hist`

Comment: yes, but it has to do some preprocessing right?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is

```
df.value_counts()
```

Or, in case you are more interested in the values of a special column:

```
df.COLUMN_NAME.value_counts(bins=5)
```

Comment: Value counts gives the count. I would want all the information, like, the bins, frequency and all other information.

Comment: Yeah, but does it make sense to have a generalized bins parameter when calling it on the df? The hist-method shows you the histogram for each applicable column and the bin size makes more sense to set column specific.
The value_count-method on the df gives you already the frequency. You can just change it to the proportions by setting "normalize=True".